# how to get the full path of a page in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I know that `var pathname = window.location.pathname;` returns path only and `var url      = window.location.href;` returns full URL.

Now suppose i have page MyPageName.aspx in the root of my site and my site can be deployed on servers serverone, servertwo & serverthree.

1. On Serverone, i want to display http://example.com/MyPageName.aspx
2. On servertwo, i want to display http://example.net/MyPageName.aspx
3. On serverthree, i want to display http://example.org/MyPageName.aspx

So how do i get the full URL path of a page in i'ts current environment with out browising to that page but knowing in advance that the page exists.

I want to display the URL some where on a master page.

Comment: I've altered the example URLs in your question to point to http://example.com, http://example.net and http://example.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `window.location.origin` to return everything up to and including the `.com`:

```
var url = window.location.origin;
-> "http://example.com"
```

As `MyPageName.aspx` appears to be static, you can then just use string concatenation to append it to the end:

```
url += "/MyPageName.aspx";
-> "http://example.com/MyPageName.aspx"
```

---

#### Demo

```js
var url = window.location.origin + "/MyPageName.aspx";
document.write(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
document.URL
```

read http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_url.asp